# How to request Restricted Data Token (RDT) from Amazon SP-API using Restsharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, amazon-selling-partner-api

To connect to amz sp-api, amazon uses Restsharp in their samples.
I have usually worked with httpwebrequests and alikes.
Following Amazon's documentation, I have been able to navigate it and create a test-environment.
Now I have hit a wall trying to request a RDP token request.

Test Scenario: I am trying to get the details of existing, unfiltered Orders. These contains customer private data. Thus, the RDP requirement.

I understand what I need to provide in my request, but I am failing in HOW to pass it through the RestRequest.
Amazon samples on this part are available on Java only, and I haven't seen any guidance on how to substitude the Java native libraries to a C# environment.
All information sites I have investigated just relink to the C# model samples or to the raw samples in their documentation.

Could someone give me an example -or point me to documentation where can I learn these bases- on how to add this raw to the request using Restsharp?

```
POST https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken
{
  "restrictedResources": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/orders/v0/orders/123-1234567-1234567",
      "dataElements": ["buyerInfo", "shippingAddress"]
    }
  ],
  "targetApplication": "amzn1.sellerapps.app.target-application"
}
```

*In case it could be useful: Here is my absolute garbage test -after too many hours and redoes of trials and error.*

```
const string END_POINT = "https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com";
const string APP_ID = "amzn1.sp.solution.*****";

public void RDT_Request()
{
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(END_POINT);
    string request_url = END_POINT + "/tokens/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "/restrictedDataToken";
    IRestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest(request_url, Method.POST);

    Console.Write("Generating request.");
    restRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    restRequest.AddHeader("user-agent", "amz sp-api demo (Language=csharp;Platform=Windows/10)");

    string jsonBody = "{\"restrictedResources\": " +
            "[{\"method\": \"GET\", " +
            "\"path\": \"/orders/v0/orders\", " +
            "\"dataElements\": [\"buyerInfo\", \"shippingAddress\"]}]," +
            "\"targetApplication\": \"" + APP_ID + "\"}";
    restRequest.AddJsonBody(jsonBody);

    try
    {
        Console.Write("Executing request.");
        var result = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - Sucess:\n" + result.Content);
            return;
        }
        throw new Exception("ERROR " + result.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" - " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading RestSharp documentation?

Comment: i am studying it right now -i know there are some blantant mistakes in my sample code-. I posted the question out of pure desperation after following amazon's documentation for days on end. Every step is a different rabbit hole. If I manage to get the token after fixing that code I will post the answer.

Comment: I can only advise about RS 107 (your code is for RS <=106). Some tips: (1) remove the content-type header (2) remove the user-agent header, use the client options UserAgent property. (3) either create a type for the payload or use `AddStringBody` with the content type. (4) remove `END_POINT` from the request URL.

Comment: @Siladamart were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Few months ago they already solved this issue, now it's working fine the way they specify [in their doc](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/tokens-api-use-case-guide#restricted-operations).

```
POST https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken
{
  "restrictedResources": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/orders/v0/orders",
      "dataElements": ["buyerInfo", "shippingAddress", "buyerTaxInformation"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**OLD**

restrictedResources isn't an array, it is a object.
Call it with a body like this one:

```
{"restrictedResources": 
{
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/orders/v0/orders",
  "dataElements": ["buyerInfo", "shippingAddress", "buyerTaxInformation"]
}}
```